# How to use MS PowerPoint to draw a straight arrow with a curved corner

Tags: graph, powerpoint

I want to draw this picture:

[image]

But I don't know how to draw the arrow. I only find straight and curved arrows while not their hybrid.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's not possible to add more elbows to an elbow arrow. Some hacks are presented here:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-you-add-more-elbows-to-an-elbow-connector/0a345a03-4bc6-4276-b9ea-0ef25d209d4d